# How to run `ant clean` from Eclipse

Tags: java, ant

Like I can run an `ant build` by right-clicking on `build.xml`, and selecting Run as --> Ant build, how do I do the same thing for `ant clean`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window/Show View/Ant, drag build.xml into that window, and you can double click on any of the tasks defined in your build.xml

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the build.xml > Run As > Ant Build...

On Targets tab, check clean option.